# How to extract and work with embedded list data in R

Tags: r, list

I have data that is like this:
It has been created from a loop object that runs an rbind at the end to append all the data together.

```
record1 <- list(ID = '11551',
  Duration = 10000,
  Sensor = 'AX152',
  codes = list('a', 'b', 'c'),
  Records= list(1231244, 12312314, 123134234, 1232345322) )

record2 <- list(ID = '11554',
       Duration = 20000,
       Sensor = 'AX151',
       codes = list('a', 'b', 'c'),
       Records= list(123, 34.12, 250, 100 ) )

record3 <- list(ID = '112',
       Duration = 1234,
       Sensor = 'AX153',
       codes = list('d', 'e', 'f'),
       Records= list(142, 172, 17.1, -1) )

Total_Set <- rbind(record1, record2, record3)
```

how to I work with the `Total_Set` and run and store a `fft()` of each of the records. When I run

```
Total_Set[[1]]
Total_Set[[2]]
```

I just get the id returned I don't seem to be able to access the Records object.

when I use:

```
view(Total_Set)
```

in rstudio I can see that all the data is there though.

Comment: Is it really the format you want to work with?

Comment: I wouldn't mind having a dataframe as Total_Set rather than a list holding lists but how do I do that in a foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

We can try

```
library(rowr)
library(dplyr)
lst <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern='record\\d+')), function(x) {
           x1 <- lapply(x, unlist)
         setNames(do.call(cbind.fill, x1), names(x1))})
bind_rows(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class(Total_Set)
```

will give that Total set is a Matrix.

```
Total_Set <- data.frame(Total_Set)
```

Will change Total_Set in a data.frame

Now you can access the first column with `Total_Set[1]`
and the first row with `Total_Set[1,]`